# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuelidate

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') Vuejs?
getting this error while using vuelidate.

import { createApp, Vue } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
createApp(App).mount('#app')

Comment: A quick check indicates that Vue doesn't have a `Vue` export. Also, isn't `use` a method of your app? https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-use

Comment: What version of Vue are you using 2.x or 3.x? Because I'm getting mixed signals here.

Comment: 3.x version i am using